# How to convert variables from version 2 to version 4 of pinescript?

Tags: pine-script

I have a pinescript written in Version #2. I am trying to convert it to version #4.
In version #2, I have something like below. What I am doing is declaring two variables persistent_bull, & persistent_bear.

After some work done in the script, I initialize this variable with values.
I check if a bull has been printed. If a bull has been printed, I turn the variable persistent_bear=0 and persistent_bull=0. I do the viceversa for bear.

When it comes to printing the signs, I check & show.

I am having trouble converting this to version 4. Is there anyone that can convert this properly for me please?

```
persistent_bull = nz(persistent_bull[1],0) 
persistent_bear  = nz(persistent_bear[1],0) 


bull = ....certain condition ....
bear =  ....certain condition ....

if bull  
    persistent_bull := 1 
    persistent_bear := 0

if bear 
    persistent_bull := 0
    persistent_bear := 1

plotshape( bull and (persistent_bull[1] != 1 or bear), style=shape.labelup, location=location.belowbar, color=colorBuy, text="Buy", textcolor=#000000, transp=0)
plotshape( bear and (persistent_bear[1] != 1 or bull), style=shape.labeldown, color=colorSell, text="Sell", location=location.abovebar, textcolor =#ffffff, transp=0)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69818048/17314002

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from the pine version 3, the variables must be defined before they actually used. So define them by setting them some values:

```
persistent_bull = 0
persistent_bear = 0
```

And then change their values from the previous bar value. Note, that there the `:=` operator is used instead of `=`

```
persistent_bull := nz(persistent_bull[1],0) 
persistent_bear  := nz(persistent_bear[1],0)
```

Luc's proposition is shorter and neat, but requires some addition changes in the code (e.g. plotting shapes before the `if bull` / `if bear` statements)

Comment: Thanks, what would the last two lines end up be? I am talking about the plot shape lines. Thanks.

Comment: If you are talking about my solution, then the rest of the code is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the 2 first lines with:

```
var persistent_bull = 0
var persistent_bear = 0
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it works, because the author uses the value from previous bar after the value on current bar could be rewritten.